# How do I configure validation error details return content-type as application/problem+json instead of application/json?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Currently when the validation type failed (here I am using data annotation ValidationAttribute), its content-type is `application/json`.

[image]

How do I configure it to return its content-type as `application/problem+json` while maintaining the error details?

Here is my controller in NET 6 Web Api project.

```
[Route("api/[controller]")]
[ApiController]
public class AccountController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IAccountService _accountService;

    /// <summary>
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="accountService"></param>
    public AccountController(IAccountService accountService)
    {
        _accountService = accountService;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    [Route("IsAccountClosed/{nric}")]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status200OK)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status204NoContent)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status422UnprocessableEntity)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status404NotFound)]
    [ProducesResponseType(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError)]
    public async Task<ActionResult> IsAccountClosed([Required] string nric)
    {
        if (!ModelState.IsValid) {
            return UnprocessableEntity(ModelState);
        }     
    }
}
```

I tried to remove the `ModelState` parameter in `UnprocessableEntity` to become `return UnprocessableEntity();`

But I can't see the data annotation validation details.

[image]

Is it because of my `ValidationFilterAttribute`?

```
public class ValidationFilterAttribute : IActionFilter
{
    public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
    {
        if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
        {
           context.Result = new UnprocessableEntityObjectResult(context.ModelState);                
        }
    }

    public void OnActionExecuted(ActionExecutedContext context) { }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need that custom filter.
The `ApiControllerAttribute` triggers `ModelState` validation automatically.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api#automatic-http-400-responses)

> The `[ApiController]` attribute makes model validation errors automatically trigger an HTTP 400 response. Consequently, the following code is unnecessary in an action method:
>
> ```
> if (!ModelState.IsValid)
> {
>     return BadRequest(ModelState);
> }
> ```

So just remove that custom filter and `ModelState.IsValid` call.

Comment: After I removed custom filter and `ModelState.IsValid`, the error becomes 500.

Comment: @Steve, That's an internal server error, so you have an exception elsewhere. You can debug that one, no?

Comment: I realized that the automatic model validation for data annotation is not working because I have this line on my program.cs `builder.Services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options
    => options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true);` . The reason I want to manually put `ModelState.IsValid` is because by default when validation fails, it returns 400 status code but I want to return it as 422 error code. I have created a new post for this.

Answer (score 0):

is marked as required. so we have to pass always something

[image]

so I tried with space and call the API

and i am getting correct response with no change in your code.

[image]

check the response content type and also annotation validation detail is mentioned.

Comment: Actually I have `ValidationFilterAttribute`. I added the code in my post. Is it caused by it?

Comment: and how do you use this ValidationFilterAttribute in your rest of your code ?

Comment: in the program.cs. `builder.Services.AddScoped<ValidationFilterAttribute>();`

Comment: I am getting correct response with or without adding this filter. and also validation will happen automatically you don't need to add this filter.